# Next.js: Mobile Safari getting “Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)” when loading hot-update.json

Tags: mobile-safari, next.js

I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` occasionally on Mobile Safari (both device and simulator) trying to load:
http://localhost:3666/_next/static/webpack/fd17da2c6b76a39ce4a1.hot-update.json, with the results that my client-side scripts do not work.

A page reload “fixes” the error. I haven’t seen it in other browsers incl. desktop Safari.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: @MoHo Sure, but where to start? Which code could be helpful here?